# Changing behavior in an existing model class in Rails (inside Redmine) - How to load it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redmine, redmine-plugins

I am building a plugin for Redmine and I have to calculate the cost of some Issues based on some customized fields.

So I made a change to class Issue (the original is a model class defined in Redmine itself) creating a "cost" method.

```
class Issue < ActiveRecord::Base
    def cost 
      return 100
    end   
end
```

The point here is how to load this change. I've tried to create a *"issue.rb"* in my *"models"* folder but the method remained unseen by views. So i appended this class definition to plugin's *"init.rb"* and it worked, but I feel this is not the right place to leave this code. My question is: **What is the "right" way to load this Issue extension to be recognized in the whole app?**

Comment: You need model class patching, look http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/Plugin_Internals.
And for work with custom fields values look my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27837058/change-value-of-custom-field-in-redmine-hook/31021921#31021921

Comment: Thanks for pointing the patch... it is more robust and safe do that way.