# Extending Redmine User Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, redmine, redmine-plugins

I'm new to Ruby on Rails and i'm trying to create a plugin.  As a first step, I'm trying to modify the User Account page with a new form field.  So far, I have the field and if I manually insert data for it in the DB, it gets pre-populated, however, I can not get it to Save data that is entered.

I'm using the `view_my_account` hook.  I also have validation setup in my patch using `validates_presence_of`.  It throws an error when i submit an empty field, and a populated field -- I assume because the field isn't connecting correctly with the `@user.save` in Redmine

here's what I have:

init.rb

```
require 'redmine'

# Patches to Redmine Core
require 'user_patch'

# Hooks
require_dependency 'account_view_hook'

Redmine::Plugin.register :myTest do
 # all plugin info
end
```

plugins/myTest/lib/user_patch.rb

```
require_dependency 'user'

module UserPatch
    def self.included(base)
        base.extend(ClassMethods)

        base.send(:include, InstanceMethods)

        base.class_eval do
            unloadable

            validates_presence_of :my_new_field

        end
    end

    module ClassMethods
    end

    module InstanceMethods
    end
end

ActionDispatch::Callbacks.to_prepare do
  User.send(:include, UserPatch)
end
```

plugins/myTest/lib/account_view_hook.rb

```
class AccountViewHook < Redmine::Hook::ViewListener
  render_on :view_my_account, :partial => 'account/my_new_field'
end
```

plugins/myTest/app/views/account/_my_new_field.html.erb

```
<p><%= form.text_field :my_new_field, :required => true %></p>
```

and the original page into which I'm hooking (redmine/app/views/my/account.html.erb)

```
<div class="contextual">
<%= additional_emails_link(@user) %>
<%= link_to(l(:button_change_password), {:action => 'password'}, :class => 'icon icon-passwd') if @user.change_password_allowed? %>
<%= call_hook(:view_my_account_contextual, :user => @user)%>
</div>

<h2>
  <%= avatar_edit_link(@user, :size => "50") %>
  <%=l(:label_my_account)%>
</h2>

<%= error_messages_for 'user' %>

<%= labelled_form_for :user, @user,
                     :url => { :action => "account" },
                     :html => { :id => 'my_account_form',
                                :method => :post } do |f| %>
<div class="splitcontentleft">
<fieldset class="box tabular">
  <legend><%=l(:label_information_plural)%></legend>
  <p><%= f.text_field :firstname, :required => true %></p>
  <p><%= f.text_field :lastname, :required => true %></p>
  <p><%= f.text_field :mail, :required => true %></p>
  <% unless @user.force_default_language? %>
  <p><%= f.select :language, lang_options_for_select %></p>
  <% end %>
  <% if Setting.openid? %>
  <p><%= f.text_field :identity_url  %></p>
  <% end %>

  <% @user.custom_field_values.select(&:editable?).each do |value| %>
    <p><%= custom_field_tag_with_label :user, value %></p>
  <% end %>
  <%= call_hook(:view_my_account, :user => @user, :form => f) %>
</fieldset>

<%= submit_tag l(:button_save) %>
</div>

<div class="splitcontentright">
<fieldset class="box">
  <legend><%=l(:field_mail_notification)%></legend>
  <%= render :partial => 'users/mail_notifications' %>
</fieldset>

<fieldset class="box tabular">
  <legend><%=l(:label_preferences)%></legend>
  <%= render :partial => 'users/preferences' %>
  <%= call_hook(:view_my_account_preferences, :user => @user, :form => f) %>
</fieldset>

</div>
<% end %>

<% content_for :sidebar do %>
<%= render :partial => 'sidebar' %>
<% end %>

<% html_title(l(:label_my_account)) -%>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

New field must be added to model first.

Commonly in Ruby on Rails You must generate and run [migration](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html), only then field performing will work.

But Redmine supports its models extension without migration and even without programming. If You want add field to `user` model, use [custom fields](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/RedmineCustomFields) that can be added in Redmine adminstrative settings. New field will be shown in `user` forms immediately, without Redmine restarting.

Of course You can use view hooks to view field as You need to and change standart performing of your field. See my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27837058/change-value-of-custom-field-in-redmine-hook/31021921#31021921) for how to work with custom field values.

Comment: Thanks for that. I did actually run a migration a babe the new field in the database. I had read about custom fields, but was curious to try and accomplish it with migrations. In that case, what am I missing?

Comment: Can You show migration code? Was migration successful and field added? Also I think that You must set field value in ```UsersController``` before saving (at ```create``` and ```update``` methods)

Comment: User gives values at @user.safe_attributes = params[:user] row in ```UsersController```. Maybe your field can't get value because of this row - inside it calls delete_unsafe_attributes method that perhaps cuts your value as unsafe

Comment: the migration was successful.  I thought simiarly about @user.safe_attributes.  This page is actually dealt with through my_controller.rb, but it has a similar line: `@user.safe_attributes = params[:user] if params[:user]`  So how do I set my new attribute to be safe?

Comment: ah found it!  I added this to `user_patch.rb`: `User.safe_attributes 'my_new_field'`.  Thanks for your help!